# pyspark dataframe withColumn command not working

Tags: python, dataframe, hive, pyspark

I have a input dataframe: df_input (***updated df_input***)

```
|comment|inp_col|inp_val|
|11     |a      |a1     |
|12     |a      |a2     |
|15     |b      |b3     |
|16     |b      |b4     |
|17     |c      |&b     |
|17     |c      |c5     |
|17     |d      |&c     |
|17     |d      |d6     |
|17     |e      |&d     |
|17     |e      |e7     |
```

I want to replace the variable in inp_val column to its value. I have tried with the below code to create a new column.

Taken the list of values which starts with '&'

```
df_new = df_inp.select(inp_val).where(df.inp_val.substr(0, 1) == '&')
```

Now I'm iterating over the list to replace the '&' column value data to it original list.

```
for a in [row[inp_val] for row in df_new.collect()]
   df_inp = df_inp.withColumn
                 (
                   'new_col', 
                   when(df.inp_val.substr(0, 1) == '&', 
                   [row[inp_val] for row in df.select(df.inp_val).where(df.inp_col == a[1:]).collect()])
                   .otherwise(df.inp_val)
                 )
```

But, I'm getting error as below:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal tpe class java.util.ArrayList [[5], [6]]
```

Basically I want the output as below. **Please check and let me know where is the error???**.
**I was thinking that two type of datatype values I'm trying to insert as per the above code??**

***Updated lines of code***:

```
tst_1 = tst.withColumn("col3_extract", when(tst.col3.substr(0, 1) == '&', regexp_replace(tst.col3, "&", "")).otherwise(""))
# Select which values need to be replaced; withColumnRenamed will also solve spark self join issues
# The substring search can also be done using regex function
tst_filter=tst.where(~F.col('col3').contains('&')).withColumnRenamed('col2','col2_collect')
# For the selected data, perform a collect list
tst_clct = tst_filter.groupby('col2_collect').agg(F.collect_list('col3').alias('col3_collect'))
#%% Join the main table with the collected list
tst_join = tst_1.join(tst_clct,on=tst_1.col3_extract==tst_clct.col2_collect,how='left').drop('col2_collect')
#%% In the column3  replace the values such as a, b
tst_result = tst_join.withColumn("result",F.when(~F.col('col3').contains('&'),F.array(F.col('col3'))).otherwise(F.col('col3_collect')))
```

***But, the above code doesn't work on the multiple iterations***

***Updated Expected Output***:

```
|comment|inp_col|inp_val|new_col                      |
|11     |a      |a1     |['a1']                       |
|12     |a      |a2     |['a2']                       |
|15     |b      |b3     |['b3']                       |
|16     |b      |b4     |['b4']                       |
|17     |c      |&b     |['b3', 'b4']                 |
|18     |c      |c5     |['c5']                       |
|19     |d      |&c     |['b3', 'b4', 'c5']           |
|20     |d      |d6     |['d6']                       |
|21     |e      |&d     |['b3', 'b4', 'c5', 'd6']     |
|22     |e      |e7     |['e7']                       |
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, **`self-join`** with **`collected list`** on **`rlike join condition`** is the way to go.

```
df.show() #sampledataframe

#+-------+---------+---------+
#|comment|input_col|input_val|
#+-------+---------+---------+
#|     11|        a|        1|
#|     12|        a|        2|
#|     15|        b|        5|
#|     16|        b|        6|
#|     17|        c|       &b|
#|     17|        c|        7|
#+-------+---------+---------+

df.join(df.groupBy("input_col").agg(F.collect_list("input_val").alias("y1"))\
          .withColumnRenamed("input_col","x1"),F.expr("""input_val rlike x1"""),'left')\
  .withColumn("new_col", F.when(F.col("input_val").cast("int").isNotNull(), F.array("input_val"))\
                    .otherwise(F.col("y1"))).drop("x1","y1").show()

#+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#|comment|input_col|input_val|new_col|
#+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#|     11|        a|        1|    [1]|
#|     12|        a|        2|    [2]|
#|     15|        b|        5|    [5]|
#|     16|        b|        6|    [6]|
#|     17|        c|       &b| [5, 6]|
#|     17|        c|        7|    [7]|
#+-------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you. @Murtihash. But, Thanks again. But, in **input_val** column I will get the values as **&RELAVENT_ID**, **MT001**, **MT002** etc instead of numbers in the example. So, how can we modify the command to get the string values replaced properly??

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `regex_replace` like this:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", regex_replace(col("inp_val"), "&", ""))
```

Comment: Thank you @Hossein, Where exactly I have to change in my code, do I have to change in the for loop. Could you explain in detail with an example. Thank you again.

Comment: you should change all of your code :))
You choose the wrong solution! iteration on the data frame is an insane job! and about example! the code that I wrote is an example. just do copy and pates

Comment: Ok, after I replace '&' with none value, I have the exact variable now. So, how to replace it with list values, from the dataframe I need to filter that based on the variable. That's why I have used for loop. Actually that's where I'm stuck!.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tryout this solution. Your approach may run into whole lot of problems.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,'a','3'),(1,'a','4'),(1,'b','5'),(1,'b','7'),(2,'c','&b'),(2,'c','&a'),(2,'d','&b')],schema=['col1','col2','col3'])
# extract the special character out
tst_1 = tst.withColumn("col3_extract",F.substring(F.col('col3'),2,1))
# Selecct which values need to be replaced; withColumnRenamed will also solve spark self join issues
# The substring search can also be done using regex function
tst_filter=tst.where(~F.col('col3').contains('&')).withColumnRenamed('col2','col2_collect')
# For the selected data, perform a collect list
tst_clct = tst_filter.groupby('col2_collect').agg(F.collect_list('col3').alias('col3_collect'))
#%% Join the main table with the collected list
tst_join = tst_1.join(tst_clct,on=tst_1.col3_extract==tst_clct.col2_collect,how='left').drop('col2_collect')
#%% In the column3  replace the values such as a, b
tst_result = tst_join.withColumn("result",F.when(~F.col('col3').contains('&'),F.array(F.col('col3'))).otherwise(F.col('col3_collect')))
```

Results :

```
+----+----+----+------------+------------+------+
|col1|col2|col3|col3_extract|col3_collect|result|
+----+----+----+------------+------------+------+
|   2|   c|  &a|           a|      [3, 4]|[3, 4]|
|   2|   c|  &b|           b|      [7, 5]|[7, 5]|
|   2|   d|  &b|           b|      [7, 5]|[7, 5]|
|   1|   a|   3|            |        null|   [3]|
|   1|   a|   4|            |        null|   [4]|
|   1|   b|   5|            |        null|   [5]|
|   1|   b|   7|            |        null|   [7]|
+----+----+----+------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: thank you. But, want to make this query dynamic -**tst_filter=tst.where(F.col('col2').isin(['a','b'])).withColumnRenamed('col2','col2_collect')**. For example we make dymamic for getting list ['a', 'b']. Since we don't know it will only have ['a, 'b'] right?

Comment: @SureshGudimetla - I have updated the answer, check it out.. I was concentrating more on where you were stuck. The generic problem of how to assign the matching column can be done in more than one ways.. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks again. But, in the below command: *tst_1 = tst.withColumn("col3_extract",F.substring(F.col('col3'),2,1))**, you have considered the substring from 2 to 1 i.e. if one digit. But in col3 column I will get the values as **&RELAVENT_ID**, **MT001**, **MT002** etc instead of numbers in the example. So, how can we modify the substring command to get the string values??

Comment: @SureshGudimetla you can just replace the value 1 as to somthing high like 1000. ````tst.withColumn("col3_extract",F.substring(F.col('col3'),2,1000))```` The results will be same .. the id value cannot be as high as 1000 right? but this will be much easier to use a regex for this.

Comment: you are correct. I tried and it is working. But, the same line of codes is not working when we have multiple hierarchy represetation in the input data, the result column is not updating properly. We have to see a solution??

Comment: yes, it can also work with multiple hierarchy. But i feel this question and discussion will become too long . Can you close this question here and post a new question for multiple hierarchy on how you tried? then the question and answer will be precise. If you prefer to continue here, can you update the input question with a sample of the multiple hierarchy?

Comment: Yes @Raghu, I have modified the question with additional requirement. You can check and let me know where is the issue I have modified the starting and ending line of code and also in join command I used **rlike** on **col3_extract** even though it is not working.

Comment: I'm thinking to do a for loop in the distinct values of col2/inp_col??